# WSO2 identity server login page is empty

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 identity server and going through their documentation for samples. But after running the server when i hit the browser with below url

https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp

i am getting empty page only (I have added the https security exception as well).
Do i need to do anything additionally ? for the admin user (admin/admin)

Comment: any exception in the logs?

Comment: No exceptions in the logs and even errors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. We need to setup only the tested jdks that are mentioned in their page. But it should also support later versions too. Looks crazy some time. I have used the latest jdk 8.161 for wso2 is 5.0.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use Identity Server 5.0.0 if you have just starting working with the product? Identity Server 5.0.0 is over 4 years old. Your can use the latest version 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Run WSO2 from command line and check out the logs for end points or wso2 services **Port already in use: xxxx** error before **java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)** which may caused by other startup process and kill them.

On linux will be:

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:xxxx`
```

(where the *xxxx* is the port number)